# Lazy evaluation with a predicate

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell that counts the elements in a list satisfying a predicate and returns `True` if the number exceeds some threshold. I have an implementation that looks like this:

```
hitsThreshold :: Int -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
hitsThreshold threshold test strs =
  (length $ filter test strs) >= threshold
```

The problem is, I want this to evaluate lazily so that it will terminate as soon as the length reaches the threshold. For example, I should be able to pass in an infinite list and it should terminate in finite time (assuming the threshold is reached eventually). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use `takeWhile` instead of `filter`. I am still too bad at Haskell to explain that properly, but it should work. Or actually just `take`, because it gets first `n` elements.

Comment: it might be helpful to look at how `length`, `take`, and `filter` are defined and think about how they compose under lazy evaluation

Comment: [IOW](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20622002/849891) `hitsThreshold threshold test strs = (length $ take threshold $ filter test strs) == threshold`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want

```
length $ take 10 $ filter even [1..]
```

[1..] is infinite, so if this weren't lazy, the program would hang.

You are pipeing [1..] through a filter `even`, then capping the number at 10....  Then you do something with that list.  Instead of `length`, you could check if it reached the threshhold by using `(>= 10) $ length`).